# SQL - Select data from three tables where one table has multiple foreign keys to the same primary key

Tags: sql, node.js

I have the following tables and relations:

[image]

When I create a `User`, that user gets a `CurrentWeek`row and that current week row in turn gets a `CurrentWeekStatus`row. The user can add food items to the `Food`table and then can choose from these food items and select a few to insert in `CurrentWeek`.

In the client I want to grab `CurrentWeek`as an object that has a list of `Food`objects and a list of their corresponding status.

I am struggling as to how to make this happen. I think this can be done by making multiple queries to the database, one to fetch `CurrentWeek` and then from this extract all the `FoodId`'s and make separate queries to fetch each `Food`. But this seems like a very bad solution.

The other solution I can think of is making a view with all the necessary data. But I don't know how to make this view and even if I manage to make the view I don't know how to separate each `Food` into different objects.

Do anyone know of a good way to accomplish this?

I use NodeJs as a REST API and Android Studio with retrofit to send REST calls.

Comment: not clear, can you supply us with the tables' schema, with the relations

Comment: Add  proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: It sounds like a college project (which is fine by me) and your tables need to be redesigned. They are not normalized and also the existence of a "Week" table look suspicious.

Comment: I will try to provide what is asked of. 
Well, I am sort of a beginner in all of this as I am trying to learn by doing. Any suggestions on how to redesign is much appreciated

Comment: @scaisEdge Not sure what to add as expected data as I am not sure myself how I want the data presented. I want a row with data for 7 different food items which I can later map into 7 different food objects in the client.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I did some reading on normalization and I feel like I have in fact normalized. If you don't agree please point out my mistakes.

Comment: using columns with sequences indicates denormalization, e.g. Food1, Food2, Food3 etc.

Comment: Also, using a "week" table is very uncommon. event happen in specific dates/timestamp. Later on you can query it and aggregate by hours, days, weeks, months, years or whatever.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz The "week" table do not indicate an event in time. In the application the user plans his weekly meals by adding several food items to the "week" table (hence Food1, Food2...) and are then presented with the meals he has chosen in a summary screen where he can select the meals he have already cooked (corresponds to status in "CurrentWeekStatus"). I am trying to fetch all food items the user chose for the week using one query. But perhaps this is not the way I should design?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Is it better to remove "CurrentWeekStatus" and instead changing "CurrentWeek" to contain 7 rows for each user, one column pointing to a food item and another describing its status? This was a decision I chose not to go with but perhaps I should reevaluate? I cannot think of any other good ways.

Comment: Exactly. Also "REMOVED" is recommended to be timestamp instead of bit and if something can be returned to the list after it has been removed than  you should consider saving an history of add/drop events.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz By "Exactly", are you refering to it being better to use 7 rows instead? I hadn't considered using a timestamp on Removed. Interesting! Thanks

Comment: Yes. I have to close it for the day. good night

Comment: Does the customer choose the food for a specific day in the week or simply 7 foods for a whole week?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Simply up to seven meals for a week without considering order. Meaning, choosing only 5 meals should also be possible, leaving the two others null valued.

Comment: I'm not sure I would even work base on weeks. This give you no flexibility. I would define a table with id,user_id,start_date and end_date and relate the invitations to that table's id.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Even though it is named "Week", it really has nothing to do with a week. It is just how I intend it to be used, but the actual user can use it in any way they want. They can go and choose up to 7 Food, but they can change the Food whenever they want. The only thing I want for this is for the user to be able to see what he has chosen in a summary view where he can chech each meal as completed when he has made them.

Comment: I suggest that you'll post a new design (in addition to the current design, for educational purposes) and we'll continue from there. Also, create some scenarios and check if the new design support them

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Sounds good. I have discussed a new design with a colleague, I will post it tonight/tomorrow when I am done making it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting StackOverflow and a few colleagues I changed the initial database schema into:

[image]

This was a design I initially chose to not go with as I thought adding one row on the `CurrentWeek` table for each user would be better than to add many rows for each user in the `PlannedFood` table. I see now however that this design have a few advantages as compared to the other design.

Designing it this way also solves my initial question as I can now grab all the rows in `PlannedFood` for a specific user, joining on `FoodId` and then map the `Food` data into a `Food`object on client-side.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz is this more like what you had in mind?